Algorithm that can solve or approximate the solution to a combination problem
I have a computational problem on my hands and I would like your help.
Here is my problem (simplified)
Let $X = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ represent a set of $n$ values.
Each value $x_i$ has a corresponding weight or value denoted by $v(x_i)$.
A subset $S$ of $X$ is denoted as $S \subseteq X$, where each element $x_i$ contributes to the total value of the subset.
The total value $\text{Value}(S)$ of a subset $S$ is given by the sum of the values of all elements in the subset:
$$
\text{Value}(S) = \sum_{x_i \in S} v(x_i)
$$
The objective is to identify all subsets $S$ where the total value exceeds 50% of the total value of all elements combined, i.e.,
$$
\text{Value}(S) > 0.5 \times \sum_{x_i \in X} v(x_i)
$$
The task is to enumerate all possible subsets of $X$ to find those that meet this criterion.
In order to do that, I need to search through all the possible subsets in the distribution in order to find the precise number of subsets that satisfy the criteria, this off course is computationally infeasible. I am looking into optimisation techniques should be employed to actually give an approximation on the number of subsets.
Thank you all for reading this through!

How big is $n$?  Do you have sample data you can share?

Pair up each subset with its complement. Either they both have exactly half of the value, or one has more than half and the other has less. So your problem is equivalent to counting solutions to the knapsack problem. In principle this is NP-complete; if the values are small integers so that many subsets have the same total value then you can augment the standard dynamic programming knapsack program with counts.

In the title, did you mean combination or computation?

@RobPratt The n can be from 10 to even 10 thousand , i want to apply this methodology in voting mechanisms in DAOs (AKA wallet balance distribution)

@PeterTaylor maybe yes , but in our case (maybe i didnt wrote it well) we just have one string of values (not both a weight and a value)

@J.W.Tanner combination is more suitable , but is also a pcomputational problem :)

For the reason that Peter gave, at least half the subsets will have at least half the total weight, so the only problem is to subtract the ones with exactly half the weight. You can just look at random subsets and see what fraction of them have exactly half the total weight.  This should give a fairly precise answer and a confidence interval without much work.
